# Rails 5 display multiple images from database field binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Postgresql table, contains multiple :binary fields. Each field stores a PNG image file.

I understand that some may suggest it is not a good practice. But many small read-only PNG images in database works better than many small files in the filesystem in this environment.

Let's say the fields are name graph1, graph2 and graph3 in the table Graph.

Right now I can only display the first field graph1 with function show_graph:

```
def show_graph
  @graph = Graph.find(params[:id])
  send_data(@graph.graph1,
    :filename => 'graph1',
    :type => 'image/png',
    :disposition => 'inline'
  )
end
```

From the view side:

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "graphs", :action => "show_graph", :id => @graph.id) %>
```

Is there a way to use the same function to send_data on graph2 and graph3, and view side differentiate each graph?

Or

Each graph require a new function in the controller and the same data would be stored 3 times in memory for what I want to do?

Thanks

Comment: Its very unclear what you asking here. Are you asking if you can send multiple images in response to a request? Then the answer is no if you want the browser to be able to make sense of the response. The code does not make sense either. You're passing `@report.id` but then fetching `@graph = Graph.find(params[:id])` so either they are the same thing or this code does not even do what you think.

Comment: @max Sorry I could not make it clear enough. I want the function show_graph to send 3 images within the same function, and the browser able to make sense on which image it is upon display.